# Two machines on same LAN unable to ping each other

Tags: networking

I have three Debian machines on the same LAN: a Raspberry Pi (wired) at address 192.168.1.5 and two laptops (wireless) on addresses 192.168.1.3 and 192.168.1.45. The two laptops cannot ping each other (in any direction) even though they are 50cm apart; however, both of them can ping the Raspberry, and even ssh to each other through it. The router (at 192.168.1.254) is the Internet provider's one (Freebox).

I don't have the first clue what is happening here. (`traceroute` is obviously unhelpful, everything being on local link). Where should I look first?

Comment: “even though they are 50cm apart” – irrelevant in a centralized WiFi network. Everything goes to the AP first. // Please check whether you enabled “AP Isolation” on your WiFi access point or router.

Comment: Some router has feature/option that isolates wifi clients from each other. Make sure you disable that.

Comment: Thanks to both of you — there was indeed such an option (but poorly named: “my personal Wifi network”). Checking this did allow clients to see each other.

Comment: I added a proper answer so this question can be marked as solved. To help find future users find it, you should [add the make and model of your router to the question](https://superuser.com/posts/1639036/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your symptoms sound very much like “AP isolation”:

- Wireless hosts cannot communicate with each other
- Wired hosts can reach everything, even wireless hosts
- Wireless hosts can reach all wired hosts

In a “regular” wireless network, the Access Point (often a WiFi router) will act as the central node for all communications. No direct host-to-host communication is possible between wireless stations. That puts the AP in a position where it can simply decide not to forward traffic from wireless stations to other wireless stations.

This is a desirable option for public WiFi networks, but not for home networks.

If you can find such an option, you should disable it.

---

You indicate the option was called “Mon réseau Wifi personnel” (“My personal Wifi network”) on your router, a Freebox from free.fr.

Comment: To be even more specific, the router is a Freebox (by French Internet provider free.fr), and the option is titled “Mon réseau Wifi personnel”.